# Image effect using CSS3 & HTML with input text and submit button

Tags: html, image, css, html5-canvas, gradient

I've login screen image as mentioned below:

[image: Login Image]

Is there any way to create similar image only using CSS3 & HTML5 ? 
Where Underline after "Username : " & "Password : "  is input type = "text" without borders (So user can type in text)

And Login is button. And all these fields are placed inside HTML Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can style the elements this way:

```
#box { /* Container box */
    width:450px;
    padding:50px;
    background:#463; /* set image here */
}
#usr, #pwd { /* input boxes */
    border:none;
    border-bottom:3px solid white;
    background:transparent;
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 24px sans-serif;
}
#box > div { /* container for lines (label + input) */
    margin-bottom:26px;
}
#box > div > label,
#box > button {
    color:#fff;
    font:bold 24px sans-serif;
}
#box > button { /* A simple button */
    background:transparent;
    border:none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#ff0;
    width:100%;
}
```

Some dummy html:

```
<div id="box">
    <div>
        <label for="usr">Username:</label>
        <input id="usr">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
        <input id="pwd" type="password">
    </div>
    <button id="login">Login</button>
</div>
```

**[Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/t4QLB/)**

[image: Board snap]

Just replace background for board with the image you are using, and use the actual font.